# why a gtkdrawarea cannot be put into a gtkbox inside a gtkscrolledwindow?

Tags: user-interface, gtk

i have a gtk program with a drawarea inside a scrolled window.  it worked (drawed) well until i restructured it with a middle layer gtkbox between them. it does not show anything in the scrolled window when the drawarea is now added to a gtkbox and then the box is added into the viewport of the scrolled window as shown in the following code.

```
GtkWidget *scrwin = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL,NULL);
gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrwin),
                GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS,
                GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC  );
.  .  .
mvbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL,0);
gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport ( GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrwin), mvbox);
.  .  . 
GtkWidget* darea = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
g_signal_connect (  G_OBJECT(darea), "draw",G_CALLBACK(draw_cb), data);
gtk_widget_set_size_request (darea, win_width, win_height);
gtk_widget_show (darea);
gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(swincr->mvbox), darea, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
```

the reason for adding the middle layer box is that there are more than one drawing areas i need to add into the scrolled window.  what would you suggest to do if adding a box is not feasible to work with scrolled window and drawing area?

Comment: and there's a `gtk_widget_show (mvbox)` somewhere?

Comment: why not use `gtk_widget_show_all(srcwin)` instead of spraying `gtk_widget_show(foo)` all over the place?

Comment: `gtk_widget_show (darea);` added for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what version of gtk you are using, but since Gtk-3.8 , gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport () had been deprecated. 
Try to use double gtk_container_add (), which is create an instance of GtkViewport and add it to scrwin.